# Can not edit crontabs in Mojave

Tags: macos, cron

Ever since APPLE's Mojave (10.14) I can not modify crontab (for root).
Release 10.14.2 did not solve this; I get "Operation not permitted".
Granting Terminal Full Disk Access did not help.
Any suggestions?
;JOOP!

Answer (score 0):

If you're receiving this error even as a root user, this is probably a security restriction enforced by [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899). You can [disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x) if you need to perform this action, but I'd recommend turning SIP back on afterwards as it helps protect your system from tampering and malware.

Comment: Strange that SIP exists since El Capitan, while this effect only shows up in 10.14.2; I don't like to disable SIP every time I must maintain my system;JOOP!

Comment: @Sciuriware SIP is updated with every major MacOS release as this article explains https://blog.macsales.com/45473-we-explain-what-system-integrity-protection-on-mac-is-and-how-to-control-it. Apple keeps using it to lock down more and more parts of the operating system unfortunately for users.

Comment: Thanks for the information: I support the idea of SIP, therefore I drop the use of crontab.